# Modify child component data added via slots from parent component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm a bit new to the component's world and trying to figure out a thing, how the parent child relationship works in components. I've seen some examples of some component libraries where they have some parent child components to be defined and those are used as the child components. For example, table and tr:

```html
<my-table>                <!-- Parent -->
    <my-tr>   </my-tr>    <!-- Child  -->
</my-table>
```

Now, I assume, that child works for parent via slots. So the parent should be defined something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
       <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now the parent element can have multiple `<my-tr>` as well. And slot should be rendering all of those. However, I am trying to a similar thing but a little more complex than that.

I am trying to create a slider with this approach. Where there is a `my-slider` component and `my-slider-item` components used to define inside `my-slider` component. And then I want to control the visibility of the child components defined in the parent component slot by modifying it's properties.

It should be looking like this:

```html
<my-slider>
    <my-slider-item>Item 1</my-slider-item>
    <my-slider-item>Item 2</my-slider-item>
    <my-slider-item>Item 3</my-slider-item>
</my-slider>
```

`my-slider` component

```html
<template>
    <div class="my-slider">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

`my-slider-item` component

```html
<template>
    <div class="my-slider__item">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now how can I know in the parent that how many `<my-slider-item>` are defined in the parent slot and based on that I want to control the visibility of the child 1 at a time as it is going to work as the slider.

I'm not sure but I missing some basic concept here which I was not getting after looking at tons of example since yesterday. If anyone can please help here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The parent-child relationship is actually established by importing the child component into the parent component, and including the child in the parent's 'components' option.

I created an example scenario with simple Parent and Child component definitions in order to show a standard relationship implementation.  Built with Vue 2 and the Vue CLI.

MySlider.vue (parent)

```
<template>
  <div class="my-slider">
    <h4>My Slider</h4>
    <my-slider-item v-for="(item, index) in sliderItems" :key="index" :sliderItem="item" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MySliderItem from './MySliderItem.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      MySliderItem
    },
    data() {
      return {
        sliderItems: [
          {
            name: 'Slider Item 1'
          },
          {
            name: 'Slider Item 2'
          },
          {
            name: 'Slider Item 3'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

MySliderItem.vue (child)

```
<template>
  <div class="my-slider-item">
    <h5>{{ sliderItem.name }}</h5>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      sliderItem: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, got that point. Now how can I access the my slider item added via slot in the parent component and manipulate those?

Comment: The first line of your question says that you are trying to figure out how the parent/child relationship works in components. This is what my example demonstrates.  Based on your example, I'm not sure why you still think you need to use slots.  An explanation would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. When I am trying to make a component that I can use it on multiple places in my website. So I would be using `my-slider` and `my-slider-item` on multiple pages to create different sliders on different pages. So on those pages I should be able to use my component like this: `<my-slider> <my-slider-item> 1 </my-slider-item> <my-slider-item> 2 </my-slider-item> </my-slider>` and at other places the data inside `my-slider-item>` would be different on different pages.

Comment: In my example you see that I am passing data from MySlider to MySliderItem via props, and then displaying the data in the template of MySliderItem, similar to how you could display data (1, 2, etc.) via a slot.  At this point, I recommend getting more knowledgeable about slots, props, and Vue in general, and then making a decision on what you want to do.  One of the main advantages of components is that they can be used as many times and on as many 'pages' as needed.  And specific data can be passed each time via props.